# GoogleMaps API v3 scrolling with mousewheel does not work

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Has anyone found a fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems this has been implemented in the official release by google since I posted this question

Answer (score 0):

This functionality isn't supported by the v3 API yet.  See the [Feature Request: Add Scroll wheel zoom in v3](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1351).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like someone has created a utility to add this functionality:

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/scrollwheelzoom/1.0/